# Shorten a Python turtle program for a house

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Below is my turtle program for drawing a yellow house. I can't figure out a way to create a `for` loop in order to keep the turtle program short. Does anyone have any idea on how to create a loop for the program below?

```
import turtle
import math
def yellowHouse () :
  wn=turtle.Screen()
  wn.title("Yellow House")
  wn.bgcolor("Blue")
  #sideLength = 200
  house=turtle.Turtle()
  Diagonal_length= 0.5*math.sqrt(2 *(200 ** 2 ))
  house.pensize(5)
  house.speed(4.6)
  house.color("Yellow")
  house.left(90)
  house.forward(200)
  house.right (135)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.right(90)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.left(135)
  house.forward(200)
  house.left(135)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.right(90)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.left(135)
  house.forward(200)
  house.right(135)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.right(90)
  house.forward(Diagonal_length)
  house.right(45)
  house.forward(200)
  house.left(90)
  wn.mainloop()
yellowHouse ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're building the house out of one shape repeated, I'd opt for *stamping* over *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def yellowHouse(side_length):
    wn.register_shape("brick", ((0, 0), (-0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -0.5)))
    house = Turtle('brick', visible=False)
    house.shapesize(stretch_wid=side_length, outline=5)
    house.color("yellow", wn.bgcolor())
    house.penup()

    for angle in range(360, 0, -90):
        house.setheading(angle)
        house.stamp()

    house.forward(side_length)
    house.stamp()

wn = Screen()
wn.title("Yellow House")
wn.bgcolor("blue")

yellowHouse(200)

wn.exitonclick()
```

This solution prints the house in the center of the screen. You pass in the size of the house you want.  (And it's about 1/3 less code.)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a loop is a good way to make the program code short, you can achieve that in many ways, in your example:

**Method 1**

use loop to draw the square, then draw the diagonal cross lines and the top

```
import turtle
def yellowHouse() :
  wn=turtle.Screen()
  wn.title("Yellow House")
  wn.bgcolor("Blue")
  house=turtle.Turtle()
  house.pensize(5)
  house.speed(4.6)
  house.color("Yellow")
  side = 200
  diag = (2*(side**2))**0.5
  ang = 90
  for i in range(4):
    house.fd(side)
    house.lt(ang)
  house.lt(ang/2)
  moves = [(diag,ang),(diag/2,ang),(diag/2,ang),(diag,ang)]
  for (move,turn) in moves:
    house.fd(move)
    house.lt(turn)
  wn.mainloop()

yellowHouse()
```

---

**Method 2**

use loop through array of steps to draw the whole shape

```
import turtle
def yellowHouse() :
  wn=turtle.Screen()
  wn.title("Yellow House")
  wn.bgcolor("Blue")
  house=turtle.Turtle()
  house.pensize(5)
  house.speed(4.6)
  house.color("Yellow")
  side = 200
  diag = (2*(side**2))**0.5
  ang = 90
  moves = [(side,ang),(side,ang),(side,ang),(side,ang),
          (0,ang/2),(diag,ang),(diag/2,ang),(diag/2,ang),(diag,ang)]
  for (move,turn) in moves:
    house.fd(move)
    house.lt(turn)
  wn.mainloop()

yellowHouse()
```

---

Notice we didn't need to import math, since we only need `sqrt()` to calculate the square root which we can achieve using the `**` exponent operator `sqrt(x)` is same as `x**0.5`

Answer (score -2):

here is your code with forloop, you have to maintain event and event value index only..

```
import turtle
import math
def yellowHouse() :
  wn=turtle.Screen()
  wn.title("Yellow House")
  wn.bgcolor("Blue")
  #sideLength = 200
  house=turtle.Turtle()
  Diagonal_length= 0.5*math.sqrt(2 *(200 ** 2 ))
  event = ["pensize","speed","color","left","forward","right","forward","right","forward","left","forward","left","forward","right","forward","left","forward","right","forward","right","forward","right","forward","left"]
  event_val = [5,4.6,"Yellow",90,200,135,Diagonal_length,90,Diagonal_length,135,200,135,Diagonal_length,90,Diagonal_length,135,200,135,Diagonal_length,90,Diagonal_length,45,200,90]
  event_zip = zip(event, event_val)
  for i,j in event_zip:
    if type(j).__name__ == "str":
        eval("house.{}('{}')".format(i,j))
    else:
        eval("house.{}({})".format(i,j))
yellowHouse()
```

Comment: Side note: you can use `zip(event, event_val)` instead of `enumerate` and indexing.

Comment: yes i forgot.. updated @nutmeg64  thanks for your reminder

Comment: In terms of making his program shorter, you do realize this solution is actually longer, character-wise, than the OP's original code!  And adding `eval` -- really?  You could have used the default turtle and built up your list `event = [pensize, speed, color, ...]` and skipped the `eval` altogether and simply applied the functions to the arguments: `i(j)`